# Full stack ReactJS suite

Tags: reactjs

As ReactJS is only view layer and works by his own, which additional libraries to use for for full stack ReactJS suite - data layer, comunication with server (AJAX calls, REST), etc. when building SPA (single page application)?

Are they any ReactJS full stack frameworks (something like AngularJS) available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReactJS alone gives you DOM rendering, but Facebook also created [`Flux`](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) which gives you an architecture in which to work. By following the rules set out by Flux, you now have a SPA with DOM rendering, data models, and communication between the two.

Of course, the SPA that you'll build with Flux is self-contained. Flux does not go so far as to provide you with tools to perform AJAX requests. You will need another library for that. However, the NodeJS community is so full of AJAX implementations, I might actually prefer it.

[`superagent`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) is a pretty popular one. (It's what I use.) You might notice it doesn't support promises, so you might also check out [`superagent-bluebird-promise`](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise), which wraps `superagent` with the [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promise library.

Another note, if you're going to use Flux, I recommend also pulling in one of the growing number of wrapper libraries that will help you reduce the boilerplate. Check out [`Reflux`](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs).

A full cycle might look like this...

`RecordList.jsx`

```
const React = require('react');
const Reflux = require('reflux');

const RecordStore = require('../stores/RecordStore');
const RecordActions = require('../actions/RecordActions');

const RecordList = React.createClass({
    mixins: [
        // auto-magically create event listeners to state change to re-render
        Reflux.connect(RecordStore)
    ],

    // There is no `getInitialState()` here, but the one in `RecordStore` is inherited.

    // load the initial data
    componentDidMount: function () {
        RecordActions.load();
    },

    // render records as a list
    render: function () {
        return (
            <li>
                {
                    this.state.records.map(function (record) {
                        return <ul>{record.name}</ul>;
                    })
                }
            </li>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = RecordList;
```

`RecordActions.js`

```
const Reflux = require('reflux');
const request = require('superagent-bluebird-promise');

const RecordActions = Reflux.createActions({
    // create an action called 'load' and create child actions of 'completed' and 'failed'
    load: {asyncResult: true}
});

// set up promise for loading records
RecordActions.load.listenAndPromise(() =>
        request.get('/records')
            .type('application/json')
            .then(res => res.body)
);

module.exports = RecordActions;
```

`RecordStore.js`

```
const Reflux = require('reflux');
const RecordActions = require('../actions/RecordActions');

/**
 * storage for record data
 */
const RecordStore = Reflux.createStore({
    // listen for events from RecordActions (Reflux)
    listenables: RecordActions,

    init: function () {
        this.data = {
            records: []
        };
    },

    // facilitate initializing component state with store data
    getInitialState: function () {
        return this.data;
    },

    /*
     * all records
     */
    getRecords: function () {
        return this.data.records;
    },

    // handle successful load of records
    onLoadCompleted: function (response) {
        this.data.records = response;
        this.trigger(this.data);
    },

    // handle failure to load records
    onLoadFailed: function (err) {
        console.error('Failed to load records', err.toString());
    }
});

module.exports = RecordStore;
```

Answer (score 4):

U could look at

http://martyjs.org/ which is an implementation of the Flux Application Architecture.

(es6 support/React native support/ Higher order components (containers: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750))

Comment: It's interesting tool! Thank you! I am looking for Catberry.js too.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search on GitHub for "react starter kits". A popular technology stack for building SPAs with React consists of:

- a Flux implementation -> you can choose one from here https://github.com/voronianski/flux-comparison
- React Router https://github.com/rackt/react-router
- Webpack + Webpack Dev Server, Babel, Gulp, ESLint + CSSLint, LESS / Sass etc.
- Jest / Mocha + Chai + Sinon
- Netflix Falcor https://github.com/Netflix/falcor (developer preview)
- some React components http://material-ui.com / https://react-bootstrap.github.io / http://react-components.com

As for starter kits, here's an interesting list of React boilerplates http://habd.as/awesome-react-boilerplates

Answer (score 0):

You could also check MERN (MongoDB, Express, ReactJS, NodeJs) full stack at [mern.io](http://mern.io/). I have been using it and it has been awesome stack. It comes with Webpack, Redux and React-Router and other basic frameworks.